# Validating the “results” of the scrollbar in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, validation, scrollbar

I have searched high and low, but found nowhere something that could help me.

Here is my problem:

I need to set a range of dates with two sliders. One slider sets the starting date of the examined period, the second sets the end date. This in itself is not a problem, but I need to validate it. E.g. when the user wants to set the starting date later than the end date (or vice versa), the program should not let him/her.

What I have tried so far:

A simple validation list would be nice. I could select the dates from an other list to use those values. But I need to use a scrolling list with one value presented at the time and with two arrows, and not a drop down one.

I tried to set validation on the cells where the dates are represented, but it only works if I enter them by hand, and does not react to the slider-given values.

I have tried setting up a macro which sets the maximum value of the starting-date-setter-scroll to the value of the ending-date-setter-scroll, but I failed miserably (and I think the answer is much more simpler than that).

I have even used IF (=IF(A2>A1;A1;"ERROR")), but again: that does not stop the user to enter the wrong data. And the sliders actual value can still be increased, so if I want to correct myself and lower its value, I may have to press it more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a macro to each scrollbar that will check if End Date is a valid date. Use the same macro for both scrollbars. In this code example, C3 has the start date, G3 has the end date. Whenever the end date is earlier than the start date, the macro will pop up a message and then set the end date equal to the start date.

```
Sub ScrollBar_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If ws.Range("G3") < ws.Range("C3") Then
        MsgBox "End date cannot be earlier than Start Date. Adjusting End date"
        ws.Range("G3") = ws.Range("C3")
    End If
End Sub
```